# IE9, IE10 image smoothing

Tags: internet-explorer

Any way to force IE9 and IE10 to make some better image downsize? In Chrome it looks perfect, but on IE looks really bad. Any way to antialias automatically resized images?

Comment: do you have some urls to the images? Also you should not force the browser to resize the image, you should do it beforehand and let it just decode the image. I also recommend using http://kraken.io to optimize the image size.

Comment: I am using `background-size:cover`

Comment: I do too, on my blog; http://love2dev.com. I am using a dataURI for my main background image. you can check it out in the F12 tools.